# Changed value through set function but; value not changing when called

Tags: c++

I have two classes an "Author" and a "Book" class. The book class constructor uses the Author constructor. The problem that is happening is that when I change a value in the author class using a setter function and then I try using the Book print function to print all the information, the new value is not printed.

I set the default constructor of Author to implement all private value.

//Author class

```
Author::Author(string name, string email, char gender)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->email = email;
    this->gender = gender;
}
Author::Author()
{
}

Author::~Author()
{
}
string Author::getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

void Author::setEmail(string email)
{
    this->email = email;
}
string Author::print()
{
    return name + " (" + gender + ") @ " + this->email;
}
```

//Book class

```
Book::Book(string name, Author author, double price)
{
    this->author = author;
    this->name = name;
    this->price = price;
}
Book::Book()
{
}

Book::~Book()
{
}
Author Book::getAuthor()
{
    return this->author;
}
string Book::print()
{
    return name + " by " + this->author.print(); 
}
```

//Main class

```
int main()
{
    Author author("Jonathan Gonzalez", "g.jonathan.com",'M');
    Book stock("NO BS! THE REALITY OF THE STOCK MARKET", author, 4.99);
    cout << author.print() << "\n" << endl;
    cout << stock.print() << "\n" << endl;

    author.setEmail("g.jonathan@gmail.com");
    stock.setPrice(2.99);
    cout << stock.print() << "\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the stock.print() function after I have changed a value using the author.setEmail() function it does not print using the new email.

OUTPUT 
Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan.com

NO BS! THE REALITY OF THE STOCK MARKET by Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan.com

NO BS! THE REALITY OF THE STOCK MARKET by Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan.com

//
//Expected OUTPUT

Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan.com

NO BS! THE REALITY OF THE STOCK MARKET by Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan.com

NO BS! THE REALITY OF THE STOCK MARKET by Jonathan Gonzalez (M) @ g.jonathan@gmail.com

Comment: You need to store pointer/reference to `author` inside `book`. Now when book is created `Book b(, author, )` a copy of author is created. The call `setEmail` doesn't affect copied object inside `book` instance. It only changes `author` as local variable inside `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I use the stock.print() function after I have changed a value using the author.setEmail() function it does not print using the new email.

That's because `stock` has its own copy of the `Author` object. Changing the state of the `author` object in `main` does not change the state of `stock.author`, the `Author` object in `stock`.

I would recommend adding a member function to `Book` to set the `Author`.

```
void Book::setAuthor(Author const& author)
{
    return this->author = author;
}
```

In `main`, call the function.

```
author.setEmail("g.jonathan@gmail.com");
stock.setAuthor(author);  // Add this
stock.setPrice(2.99);
```

Now, the call to print will work as per your expectation.

```
cout << stock.print() << "\n" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Author` inside `Book` class as a pointer.

```
class Book
{
    Author* author;

    Book(string name, Author* author, double price)
    {
        this->author = author;
    }
}
```

Then pass the address

```
Book stock("...", &author, 4.99);
```